# how to define a radial search area around a lat/lng position?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project, where each user has its own coordinates lat / lng, extracted from google geocoder service...

now I want to implement a search function -> you can enter the radius (km) and if someone is within the radius, the profile will pop up...

it wasnt to difficult to get this to work, when the search area is actually a square, but how do I get this to work, with a circle as search area?

here is the code, to build the "search" part of the mysql query:

```
// This is the location of the user who submitted the search function.
mysql_select_db("$db_profile");
$sql = "SELECT location_lat,
            location_lng
    FROM location
    WHERE id = '$global_id'";
$sql = mysql_query($sql);   
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

// The coordinates of the user.
$lat = $row['location_lat'];
$lng = $row['location_lng'];

// the entered radius in kilometers - here it is converted to degree (1° = 111km).
$x_degree = $global_search_radius_value / 111;

// define the search grid (it is a squere! but I want a circle!).
$lat_neg = $lat - $x_degree;
$lat_pos = $lat + $x_degree;

$lng_neg = $lng - $x_degree;
$lng_pos = $lng + $x_degree;

// build the search part of the mysql query
$heredoc_search_radius = <<<EOD
AND ($db_profile.location.location_lat > '$lat_neg' 
    AND $db_profile.location.location_lat < '$lat_pos'
    AND $db_profile.location.location_lng > '$lng_neg'
    AND $db_profile.location.location_lng < '$lng_pos')
EOD;
```

how can I use a circle instead of the squere!?

Answer (score 0):

To keep this performant, your best bet could be to put your data into a system such as Apache Solr http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html which will let you perform a geospatial search out-of-the-box.

Solr will ensure your queries stay blindingly fast, regardless of the number of data points you have.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

In mysql it would look like this, not suer if ABS is necessary, in theory it should not be.

`WHERE SQRT(POW(ABS($db_profile.location.location_lat - $lat), 2) + POW(ABS($db_profile.location.location_lng - $lng), 2)) < $radius`

If you will need quicker search, keep calculated distances in other table. However this would use n^2 rows to store.